# Multithreaded Programming with the Command Pattern, How can I open the "Listing"

Tags: multithreading, command, design-patterns

I have read the article "[Multithreaded Programming with the Command Pattern](http://www.drdobbs.com/184416612;jsessionid=Z0WDLSISVGJPJQE1GHRSKH4ATMY32JVN)", but I can't open the "Listing" to view the example code, any body have the example code? thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

That had disappointed me too, but then I clicked on the pagination links right after the article text and I succeeded.

Just in case: here are links:

- [Listing 1. Thread creation with the CreateThread() function](http://drdobbs.com/184416612?pgno=2)
- [Listing 2. Thread synchronization using mutex variables](http://drdobbs.com/184416612?pgno=3)
- [Listing 3. This app reads messages from a queue by using a thread pool](http://drdobbs.com/184416612?pgno=4)
- [Listing 4. The Command pattern](http://drdobbs.com/184416612?pgno=5)
- [Listing 5. The threads call the Execute() function on the Commands that they receive](http://drdobbs.com/184416612?pgno=6)

By the way, your link to the article itself won't open for me, probably because of session ID in it, so here is link that works for me: [Multithreaded Programming with the Command Pattern](http://drdobbs.com/184416612).